# Как получить код кириллицы?

Tags: c++, c

Не могу конвертировать кириллицу в числовой код.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char sim = 'Q';
    int kod = (int)sim;
    printf ("%d\n", kod);
}
```

С помощью данного кода получается получить код только латиницы, при вводе кириллицы компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
Test.c: In function 'main':
Test.c:5:13: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   char sim = '╨░';
         ^~~~
Test.c:5:13: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78185/discussion-on-question-by-levayanogakabargi----).

Comment: Этого в общем случае нельзя достичь, так как тема обширная и глубокая (кодировки, о которых тут чаще всего говорят — только вершина айсберга).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужно сохранять переменные в типах wchar_t и wint_t.
Примерчик:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    if (! setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")) {
        exit(1)
    }
    printf("%lc, %lc, %ls\n", (wint_t)9213, (wchar_t)"ваш символ в юникоде, размер 2 char"," строка в юникоде");
}
```

вот *наглядный* [пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94cfd56667ff650a) как это работает с кодом автора.

Comment: Если редактор использует кодировку UTF-8 - это никак не поможет.

Comment: К вопросу UTF8 имеет какое то отношение? и кстати поможет, вам неплохо бы ознакомиться с locale.h и wchar.h хотя бы с помощью man документации

Comment: Почему мне? В вопросе как раз UTF-8.

Comment: Именно вам, если есть непонимание что есть размерность символа. Тип warchar используеться для всех 'типов кодирок' отличных от ASCII.

Comment: "Не могу конвертировать кириллицу в числовой код." - где тут упоминание о UTF8? Это ваше предположение, кстати неверное.

Comment: Я с кодировками знаком хорошо. Есть ещё кодировка исходного текста страницы, и кодировка, которую понимает компилятор. В некоторых случаях они в винде могут конфликтовать.

Comment: Информация для понимания вопроса о [размерности символов](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Широкий_символ). Кодировка и представление набора байт не есть одно и тоже, для поддержки обработки разных кодировок в программе надо писать собственный код или использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: @NewView на сколько я понимаю вы хотите сказать что русские 
 двух байтовые символы переполняют одно байтовый char. Я к сожалению не достаточно информирован в области работы с предложенными вами библиотеками, пойду восполнять пробелы) нет ли альтернативы для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: да, именно так, символ не влезает в желаемый тип, вот на русском доступное [описание](https://habr.com/post/164193/) например. Альтернатива в примере на верху, использовать иные типы из wchar.h

Comment: Для обработки и конвертации кодировок в любом случае удобнее использовать готовые функции, смотреть [iconv.h](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html) и Гугл конечно :)

Comment: @NewView есть ли варианты использовать массивы/указатели?

Comment: @NewView, JFYI: `wchar_t` не работает для всего юникода, и более того считается устаревшим, а ещё, что важно, очень много косяков с ним, почитайте как-нибудь соответствующие дайджесты. Ну и недаром же появились `char16_t` , `char32_t` и API вокруг них (это как раз не для UTF-8).

Comment: @0andriy, wchar_t есть стандарт, поддерживаемый на всех системах и с любыми версиями компиляторов. Что нельзя сказать о char16_t , char32_t. Всегда есть новые изыски и проверенные решения. wchar_t являеться внутренним типом и не зависит от кодировки, хотя являеться компиляторно-зависимым.Для этого типа существуют проверенные и обкатанные решения, что не маловажно. Человеку надо было решить задачу, а не заниматься изучением вопросов совместимости.

Comment: @0andriy, флуд аргументированный :), не разбрасывайтесь им, он не имеет ценности, и всякого не по теме.

Comment: @NewView, ну вы упёртый же однако. https://www.moria.us/articles/wchar-is-a-historical-accident/

Comment: @0andriy, инструменты для вменяемой работы с char16_t , char32_t отсутствуют в С. Мало того, это принято начиная со стандарта C11 и устарело и считается deprecated в новом стандарте C17. Не вижу смысла продолжать эту дискуссию, она не о чем, и с вашей стороны больше походит на тролинг.

Comment: И для особо продвинутых, char16_t = unsigned int, char32_t = unsigned long. :) чего тут спорить то.. темы просто нет.

Comment: Учитывая ваш пример ниже, троллинг как раз идёт с вашей стороны. Посмотрите исходники любого вменяемого офисного пакета.

Comment: @NewView, и кстати, то, что вы написали как эквивалент типов, не соответствует действительности. Было бы неплохо в подтверждение ваших слов видеть цитаты из стандарта, на которые вы ссылаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

в продолжение, напишу тут:
вот простенький пример как преобразить данные кодировок в тип wchar_t, надеюсь поможет, и даст точку с чего начать.

```
#include <iconv.h>

iconv_t cd;
char out[9*2];
wchar_t in[9*2+1] = "ваш текст";
size_t inl = sizeof(in), outl = sizeof(out);

cd = iconv_open("utf-8", "wchar_t");
iconv(cd, (char **)&in, &inl, &out, &outl);
iconv_close(cd)
```

Comment: Ну... как вариант. Если не может выставить кодировку исходников - пусть перекодирует. Костыль - но сработает.

Comment: `wchar_t in[] = L"ваш текст";`? или `wchar_t * in = L"ваш текст";`?

Comment: поправил, спасибо, но это упрощенный пример, под строки надо естественно выделять память стандартными средствами, это скелет телодвижений скорее :)

Comment: Почему же? `wchar_t in[] = L"ваш текст"; char out[sizeof(in)];` Красиво.

Comment: текст у автора вряд ли будет статичным, так что блок с *alloc ему будет необходим, для wchar есть свои функции wstrlen итд

Comment: Зачем вы два ответа нагенерировали, когда можно красиво в одном?